# joomla and nivo slider woes

Tags: joomla, nivo-slider

So in short, i dont mess with Joomla at all (been a few years) and today i get a "hey can you fix this" problem which ive dedicated too much time to and i cant seem to figure out the problem. i definitively need help

The website is http://www.inrecordtime.net

The problem is that, the slider doesn't fully work and by "*fully*" i mean that, everything is in place, ive checked paths and replaced the original files with updated versions, also changed out the google hosted cdn version of jquery with a local copy, checked image paths etc....and nothing.

What happens is that when the page loads, the first image on the slider loads, but the slider doesnt "slide" its just one image in place.

- Ive tested the images on firebug and they load fine.
- Ive removed the parameters in the slider and left it as a regular function call like `jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider();` and nothing.
- i placed back the parameters and within the slider, one of the parameters is `startSlide`
  and this parameter instructs the slider to start at a specific image in the list.

currently its at "0" which is the first image, when i change it like so `startSlide: 2` for example, and then reload the page, the slider starts at the second image (which indicates the not fully working part of it all ) but again, the slider doesnt "slide".

I suggested to the higher ups that instead of mixing it all up, to let me hard code it but that was shot down because they want them to be able to change the images.

Im really lost so any help or code or suggestion etc, i humbly appreciate.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the errors that are popping up in my console, you likely need to update the `jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js` file to a later version, which you can grab from here: https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider/blob/master/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js

The version you are running relies on the `live` function in jquery, which was deprecated and I think is now removed, hence the errors being thrown now that you use the latest jquery version. The new version of nivo slider has been updated to rely on the new `on` function of jquery and should run.

Looks like your version is located here: http://www.inrecordtime.net/templates/IRT/scripts/nivo-settings/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js